# Doubt on rechargable LED emergency bulb

Tags: led

I have recently seen a [rechargeable LED emergency bulb on Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/127019135/smartchargetm-never-be-in-the-dark-again) and I was wondering how it works.

In the event of a power failure, the LED bulb will turn ON automatically. That is, when the switch is ON and mains power goes off, the bulb will detect that and turn ON. If the switch is OFF the bulb will not turn ON. When mains are ON and the switch is ON the bulb will start recharging again.

It is just like a normal bulb. See the [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcKbLnUz1bI)

My question is, how does the bulb detect the event of mains failure? Can somebody give me a hint on this?

Comment: The simplest example would be a normally closed relay.

Comment: when power is out, there is still some residual voltage on the lines. i think that the bulb detects the low voltage and turns on.

Comment: Ah.. that's the question. You mean why it is not goin ON when just switched off? Because it looks like it is coming with the special switch together... And looks like it is not an actual product but a bait for investors.

Comment: So they show how it is not switching off when they switch off the power to it. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think it is detecting voltage variation on neutral line?

Comment: Just sounds like the exit signs that come on when the power fails...

Comment: @SolarMike, not like that at all.

Comment: Something odd about that video at 1:14. You can see the power bar is plugged in to something else.. Not saying it is fake, but they could have made it a lot more convincing.

Comment: Hmm... first I figured it was monitoring line resistance, but when he unplugs the power bar and the switch still works that goes out the window... Interesting, assuming it is real.

Comment: It could be monitoring difference in line impedance I guess....

Comment: However, according to the comments page.. apparently they do not work https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/127019135/smartchargetm-never-be-in-the-dark-again/comments

Answer (score 7):

The Youtube video analysis is quite complete: The bulb tries to pass a tiny DC current (battery voltage through two 1 MΩ resistors) through the line connections, on the assumption that there is SOME DC path through the network at all times (even if it's through the pole transformer).

The light comes on if it receives full voltage from the line; this is "normal operation".

The light also comes on if there is no line voltage, but there's a DC path between its two contacts; this is "emergency operation".

Note the restrictions: The special bulb must be the ONLY bulb on the switched circuit. If there were other regular bulbs, they would provide the DC path and the special bulb would stay on all the time.

The demo video is actually using two outlet strips. One is plugged into the wall, and the black lamp is plugged into it, along with the second (switched) outlet strip that we see sitting on the table.

When he unplugs the first outlet strip from the wall to simulate the power failure, it is the black lamp that provides the DC path that allows the special bulb to switch on and off. Without that black lamp, the demo would have failed! (Also, if the presenter had switched off the black lamp during the simulated outage, the smart bulb would have switched off, too.)

Comment: U-Tube video is not actually the same lamp, but answer still makes sense.

Comment: @Trevor_G: Yes, I realized that. The Youtube bulb puts out a lot less light when it's operating from battery (5 LEDs rather than the 16 that are operating from line voltage). The Kickstarter bulb appears to operate at full brightness in both modes, which raises questions about its runtime on battery.

Comment: Yup, and the comments page has some of the worst feedback I have even seen on there...

Comment: Still confused about how it detects mains power failure even when wall switch is ON. Can somebody give me some hint on this.

Comment: It detects mains power failure by the fact that there is no line voltage across its terminals. The more interesting question is, how does it know the switch is on even when the mains are off? That's what the tiny DC current is for.

Comment: The tiny DC current is flowing through the negative terminal, then through other equipments and complete the path at the positive terminal. Is that correct?In household connections, wall switch is only for phase and neutral is common.

Comment: Yes, that's correct,

Comment: But this small DC Volts from battery is sufficient enough to drive such a long path?  If the mains are live how this DC current will get blocked and transistor M6 in Youtube video turns OFF.

Comment: That's what the two diodes and the capacitor in M6's base circuit are for. When line voltage is present, the capacitor charges up to a voltage that is greater than the battery voltage. This reverse-biases the second diode, keeping M6 cut off. The 1M resistor between B and E takes care of any leakage current.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71718/discussion-between-geo-and-dave-tweed).

Answer (score 2):

If the power has failed somewhere on the grid, the residential line impedance is still low from the transformer secondary winding.

The AC light switch can now enable the internal LiPo battery to power the Shunt LEDs in the circuit.   There is  a slow rise time to charge up the capacitor before the DC battery can operate.

So the breakers and outside transformer must still be connected for this to work.   **Correction: Clive demonstrates in the Youtube video that even finger resistance across the Edison contacts is enough to enable the emergency light** (with a power failure and external switch closed.)

[image]

Judging by the kickstarter investor feedback, they were not too happy with the results. The Youtube product had quality issues but at least worked.

Answer (score -1):

When there is power the bulb works normally. If there is no power you have to short circuit the terminals for the bulb to burn on battery. When it is in the circuit and when power goes off the terminals of the bulb get connected together through other loads in the circuit and so it burns on battery.

Comment: This answer does not fit the described behavior in the question.